# How to pass a JSON value to a function?

Tags: css, json, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a simple label in the app that would show whether the gate is open or not. That is, for this I can use a boolean type that returns `true/false`, but I would like it to display yes/no on the page instead of true/false and add a translation in Dutch, that is, depending on how the user initially sets the language of the app, the yes/no message will be displayed in that language. In the app, I already have the other . translatedor false.
That is, half th success is. The function works. However, instead of this true/false, I would like to put yes/no in 2 language versions.
I was thinking of adding something like translations in the `JSON` file, for example: "true": "yes" and "false": "no" and the same in the Dutch version, because currently the value of true/false is returned automatically, however, I don't know how I could pass something like that to the code line shown above. Does anyone have an idea how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use build-in angular translator or install [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). If you use 2nd option your code will look like this:

```
<dd class="col-sm-6">{{gate.open ? ('gate_open' | translate) : ( 'gate_closed' | translate) }} </dd>
```

Ofc you have to add translation to json or ts files